# vim error each time, "programs.py" [New File] Error detected while processing function kite#bufenter[2]

Tags: vim

When I try to open a file like programs.py using vim I get the same message and error each time even though I also tried another file. 
The line 1 and line 7 is the comment part in programs.py. So it shouldn't have any error.

"programs.py" [New File]
Error detected while processing function kite#bufenter[2]..21_launch_kited[2]..kite#utils#launch_kited[1]..kite#utils#kite_running[9]..kit
e#async#sync[7]..24_on_close_vim[1]..24_async_sync_output:
line    1:
E121: Undefined variable: v:t_list
E15: Invalid expression: type(a:output) == v:t_list
line    7:
E121: Undefined variable: output
E15: Invalid expression: output

Answer (score 0):

> Error detected while processing function kite#bufenter

This means you've got an error by autoloaded function which probably originates in the plugin named ["kite"?](https://kite.com/integrations/vim/)

> E121: Undefined variable: v:t_list

This means Vim doesn't have an internal variable named "v:t_list". This must be due to the severely outdated Vim version. (v:t_xxx constants were added to Vim 7.4.2071 in Jul 2016).

Hence, you have two solutions: (1) remove the plugin, or (2) update your Vim to the latest version.